# Elementor Pop-up with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popup, elementor

I have a problem. I made a custom Pop-up using elementor and now added a custom jQuery code for the pop-up menu to close on the menu-item click. I have ordered the Elementor to open via action in elementor and close via the code. [Picture of elementor action for popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ET0.png)

The code is following.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
$(document).on('click','.elementor-location-popup .menu-item', function(event){
elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup({}, event );
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is, that every click on different elements on the page, for example the admin bar, the contact form etc, the popup opens, event though not ordered to do so.
Has anyone had the same issue with elementor popup?
Has it something to do with the jQuery document value? Or should I seek help from elementor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix. It is an Elementor bug.. They still have not fixed it, even with the latest update. The issue was not with jQuery code, but with Elementor settings.

I had to eliminate all the popup conditions and triggers from elementor side and just use a dynamic elementor button opening and jQuery button closing.
Somehow the triggers produced the bug, that opened the popup on a random page click.